# Google Chrome in a business environment?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions

Is it possible to install Google Chrome in a business environment where the browser is locked down.  For example, the user should not be able to change settings, and the user should not be able to install/remove any apps/extentions either.

Comment: Have you checked here already? http://www.google.com/apps/intl/en/business/chromebrowser.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a distribution for enterprise/business that allows for more customisation.

http://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/business/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [portable version](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable) instead, it works well with me since I don't have right to install new application on windows server :)